# Froala Editor- Not getting the focus with place holder text

Tags: froala

I have an issue when using the Froala Editor. I am unable to get the focus when I click the editor with place holder text. I have to click after the place holder text to get the focus.   I have also noticed that events like  `froalaEditor.click`, `froalaEditor.commands.after`, `froalaEditor.focus` are not triggering when I click on the place holder text. If I click after the text, then everything seems to be OK. My place holder text is very long so its a bit annoying for the users to always goto to end of the place holder and click to get the focus.
I am using Angular. Can anyone help on this?

```
<div id="problemStatment" name="problemStatment" 
    [froalaEditor]="Options" 
     [(froalaModel)]="modelname"  [(ngModel)]="modelname" 
    style="width:100%;max-height:370px;height:500px;">
</div>

this.Options = {
            key: 123456789,            
            height: 320,
            maxHeight: 320,
            quickInsert: false,
            placeholderText: "explain xxxx<br/>explain yyyyy<br/>explain zzz",
            toolbarSticky: true,
            charCounterCount: false,
            toolbarInline: false,
            toolbarButtons: ['paragraphFormat', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'cut', 'copy', 'paste',
                 'bold', 'italic',  'underline', 'color', 'align', 'formatOL',
                 'formatUL', 'outdent', 'indent', 'insertImage', 'spellChecker'],
            toolbarVisibleWithoutSelection: false,
            backgroundColor: '#f0f',
            required: true,
            imageUploadURL: '/path/path/api/',
            imageUploadMethod: 'POST',
            imageMaxSize: 1024 * 1024 * 1,
            events: {                             
                'froalaEditor.commands.after': this.OnChange.bind(this),
                'froalaEditor.image.beforeUpload': this.beforeImageUploadEvent.bind(this),
                'froalaEditor.click': this.OnChange.bind(this), 
                'froalaEditor.focus': this.OnChange.bind(this), 
             }
```